# How to implement 3D coordinates in Gauss Markov Mobility Model using Sim2net?

Tags: python-3.x, vector, 3d, 2d, coordinates

The receivers in the project I'm working on have 3D coordinates like (x, y, z).

I can simply model the mobility for 2D coordinates like (x,y) by using the GaussMarkov package.

I want to model the mobility for 3D coordinates; is there a way to do this? Nothing that I could locate in the documentation.

https://github.com/mkalewski/sim2net

i implemennted on 2D coordinates. i need to do it for 3d coordinates

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)